# AUCTeX Preview rung error

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

I'm new to emacs and AUCTeX and I'm having a problem with document preview (`C-c C-p C-d`). My LaTeX file is the following

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduzione}

\emph{This is important}

$$
e^{\pi i}+1=0
$$

\cite{Col73}

\bibliography{bibliography}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

and, of course it compiles. When I try to preview it I get the following messages:

```
Running `Preview-Ghostscript' with ``/usr/bin/rungs -dOutputFile\=\(pippo.prv/tmp6365EzV/pr1-\%d.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r99.0866x99.0685''

Preview-Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Feb 15 11:11:16
Unable to read environment locale:exit now.

Preview-Ghostscript exited abnormally with code 1
```

My emacs version is 25.3.1, GS is 9.22. I read around that there were some incompatibility between such versions.
Do you know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just update your AUCTeX to the last version 12.1.  I suggest you use the version on ELPA.  This is the entry in the release note of 11.92:

> preview-latex is compatible with Ghostscript 9.22 where the operator
>   `.runandhide` is removed.  All occurrences of `.runandhide` in
>   preview-latex are replaced by alternative code making it work with
>   Ghostscript 9.22 again.

As a side note, don't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX documents.  It may result in weird vertical spacing issues.  Load the package `amsmath` and use one of its environments.

Comment: The version of my AUCTeX (installed with package manager) is 12.1.0. I tried to do the preview again and what I get are work-in-progress triangular symbol instead of formulae. The error is `Preview-PDF2DSC exited abnormally with code 1 at Fri Feb 16 10:04:55
PDF2DSC sentinel: Opening input file: No such file or directory, /home/.../main.prv/tmp2757gyG/preview.dsc`
What should I do? How to remove `.runandhide` operator?

Comment: @MaPo - The error you describe is now something different.  I suggest you try to construct and show a minimal .tex file exhibiting your problem.  Also your `.emacs`-config reg. AUCTeX might be helpful.  Please do `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET` to see if you have any conflicting versions/files installed.